# No products are showing after upgrade Magento 2.1.7 (but visible by search)

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I have upgraded to Magento 2.1.7 and suddenly no products appear on the website, only visible by the search. I upgrade by command line:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

I am working for years with Magento now and I know all the steps that should be verified (indexing / cacheflush / opcache flush / stock / visible in / bound to the right category / selected the right website for the product...

But this time I just can't get it back to work. I also tried:
php bin/magento indexer:reset
and reindex again, but doesn't work either.

I don't see any errors in var/log/system.log

So no idea what I should do now. Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if `catalog_category_product_index` table is filled. If so the only thing that left is going with xdebug and see what kind of query is done on the database and trying to find which part of the query does not work.

Comment: catalog_category_product_index was filled, truncated it and reindexed and it's filled again but still don't show on the website.
Thanks for the tip, I will try that out

Comment: Are you using some sphinx or elastic search engine?

Comment: Yes, elastic search engine. Does it have something to do with that?

Comment: Most likely. Do you see any indexers related to elastic search? Most probably your products were not exported to search engine as it has its own database with information and data in magento need to be stnchronized with elastic search db

Comment: Oh perfect! That fixed my issue! Thanks a lot. You should post your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some kind of external search engine installed (like Sphinx or ElasticSearch) it may not be properly updated. Do you see any indexers related to elastic search? Most probably your products were not exported to search engine as it has its own database with information and data in magento need to be stnchronized with elastic search db

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need check out steps below:

- reindex
- Magento cache
- Varnish cache

Comment: I checked that out already..